# how to make a transparent form when a VCL Style is enabled?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I'm using the following code to make a form transparent, but when the application has a VCL style enabled the form is paint with the background color of the VCL style instead of be transparent.

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure CreateParams(var Params:TCreateParams); override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
 inherited CreateParams(Params);
 Params.ExStyle := WS_EX_TRANSPARENT or WS_EX_TOPMOST;
 //Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_LAYERED;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Brush.Style:=bsClear;
 BorderStyle:=bsNone;
 //SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Handle, 0, 230, $00000002);
end;
```

FYI The code works fine if the the vcl style is set to `Windows`.

Exist another way to make a form transparent to workaround this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like a bug to me. The VCL Styles use *Style hooks* to intercept the paint methods and the Windows messages related to these operations, So in this case you must focus your atention in the `PaintBackground` method of the  [`TFormStyleHook`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TFormStyleHook) class located in the `Vcl.Forms`, from here you create a new style hook class (which descends from *TFormStyleHook*), override the `PaintBackground` method, fix the code and finally before to use it call the RegisterStyleHook method to register the New *style hook*. check this article [`Fixing a VCL Style bug in the TPageControl and TTabControl components`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/fixing-a-vcl-style-bug-in-the-tpagecontrol-and-ttabcontrol-components/) to see an example.

**UPDATE**
Check this sample

```
unit Unit138;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm138 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure CreateParams(var Params:TCreateParams); override;
  public
  end;


var
  Form138: TForm138;

implementation

 Uses
   Vcl.Themes,
   Vcl.Styles,
   uPatch;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm138.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
 inherited CreateParams(Params);
 Params.ExStyle := WS_EX_TRANSPARENT or WS_EX_TOPMOST;
end;

procedure TForm138.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Brush.Style:=bsClear;
 BorderStyle:=bsNone;
end;

initialization
 TStyleManager.Engine.UnRegisterStyleHook(TForm, TFormStyleHook);//unregister the original style hook
 TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TForm, TMyStyleHookClass); //register the new style hook

end.
```

### The New Style Hook Class

```
unit uPatch;

interface

uses
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Forms;

type
  TMyStyleHookClass= class(TFormStyleHook)
  protected
   procedure PaintBackground(Canvas: TCanvas); override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.Types,
  Vcl.Themes;


procedure TMyStyleHookClass.PaintBackground(Canvas: TCanvas);
{This is only a basic sample for fix a specific scenario}
var
  Details: TThemedElementDetails;
  R: TRect;
begin
  if StyleServices.Available then
  begin
    if (GetWindowLong(Form.Handle,GWL_EXSTYLE) AND WS_EX_TRANSPARENT) = WS_EX_TRANSPARENT  then
    if Form.Brush.Style = bsClear then Exit;

    Details.Element := teWindow;
    Details.Part := 0;
    R := Rect(0, 0, Control.ClientWidth, Control.ClientHeight);
    StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, Details, R);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

On a separate note, have you tried using the `TransparentColor` and `TranparentColorValue` properties instead of manipulating the window styles in `CreateParams()`?

Comment: Yes i Tried but doesn't work. I set these values `TransparentColor:=True; TransparentColorValue:=TStyleManager.ActiveStyle.GetStyleColor(scGenericBackground);`

Comment: Are you sure `scGenericBackground` is the right color actually being used during painting, and that `GetStyleColor()` is returning the correct `TColor` value?  Have you tried hard-coding the `TransparentColorValue` property to a specific `TColor` value that you know is being shown onscreen?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, maybe can you edit your question adding the code which you suggest?.

Answer (score 1):

I use OverridePaintNC := False to prevent draw Styles on NC area. And there is OverrideEraseBkgnd too. Maybe this help.