# UpdateLayeredWindow with normal canvas/textout

Tags: delphi, winapi, opengl, directx

Is there a way to draw on form with canvas and then use the updatelayeredwindow so not the form will be visible but the text, like a transculent form showing only text? if not, then is there a way to make some sort of transculent form with only the canvas (opengl/directx) maybe? i would like to draw with commands on the top of all windows.

Comment: Does this link help ? : [how-to-make-a-transparent-form-when-a-vcl-style-is-enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317617/how-to-make-a-transparent-form-when-a-vcl-style-is-enabled)

Comment: thats helpful but im searching for a Transparent form, opaque AA label or something...

Comment: Do you want to create something like on screen displayed text ? If so, then take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5200707/960757). [Dorin Duminica](http://stackoverflow.com/users/497849/dorin-duminica) created a component for it ;)

Comment: @TLama, thats almost exacly what im looking for, i think that with it i can create something that is static?

Comment: i need the form to be totaly transculent :( this component cant help me sorry...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `TransparentColor` property of the form to 'True', then set the form color to the same color of `TransparentColorValue`, and all of the form's client area will be transparent. If the Delphi version you use does not have the 'TransparentColor[Value]' properties you can achieve the same with API calls:

```
  Color := clBlack;
  SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
      GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_LAYERED );
  SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Handle, 0, 255, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

will make the forms client area transparent. You can paint on the canvas as you normally would:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
  Canvas.TextOut(0, 0, 'Text');
end;
```

Of course you can also put a label on the form having a font color anything different then the transparent color.

Comment: this is soooo simple that i eaven forgot about that :) thats what i almost wanted. now i need to make it top-most and that i can click throu that :)

Comment: For click through add `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` to the style ;)

Comment: TransparentColorValue and TransparentColor helped a bit BUT!... how to remove this white outline from that label? is there a way? 
[http://i42.tinypic.com/1z5lw7d.png](http://i42.tinypic.com/1z5lw7d.png)

Comment: .. and form style 'fsStayOnTop'

Comment: @Talibek - What color is your label?

Comment: clWindowText is the font color, and clBtnFace is the color

Comment: the same color as the TransparentColorValue

Comment: @Talibek - The label's font color should be different than the transparent color, the whole point is that one of the colors on the form's surface is made transparent. But I guess what you are seeing may be some antialisaing artifact due to changed background color. If so, you might need to drop using a label and play with 'lfQuality' of a 'LOGFONT'. Or try to achieve some outline effect by using more than one label having different font colors perhaps..

Comment: @Talibek - I can have a label without a visible outline by setting the background to a color that is slightly different than 'clWindowText'. F.i. `BgColor:=graphutil.ColorAdjustLuma(clWindowText,10,False)`, set form's 'Color', 'TransparentColorValue', and label's 'Color' to this value, label's font color would be 'clWindowText'. It helps getting rid of the outline but also reduces anti-aliasing so it now looks uglier. And when there's no outline, it's not visible when the color under the form is similar. I guess this is quite a different problem then transparency, consider asking a question.

Comment: Sertac is a genius.