# How draw a control over a WS_EX_LAYERED form?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm using this code do draw a transparent form of a solid color.

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  BlendFunction: TBlendFunction;
  BitmapPos: TPoint;
  BitmapSize: TSize;
  exStyle: DWORD;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  exStyle := GetWindowLongA(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
  if (exStyle and WS_EX_LAYERED = 0) then
    SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle or WS_EX_LAYERED);

  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    Bitmap.SetSize(Width, Height);
    Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clRed;
    Bitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height));
    BitmapPos := Point(0, 0);
    BitmapSize.cx := Bitmap.Width;
    BitmapSize.cy := Bitmap.Height;
    BlendFunction.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
    BlendFunction.BlendFlags := 0;
    BlendFunction.SourceConstantAlpha := 150;
    BlendFunction.AlphaFormat := 0;

    UpdateLayeredWindow(Handle, 0, nil, @BitmapSize, Bitmap.Canvas.Handle,
      @BitmapPos, 0, @BlendFunction, ULW_ALPHA);

    Show;
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  Message.Result := HTCAPTION;
end;

end.
```

But none of the controls appears in the form , already I read this question [UpdateLayeredWindow with normal canvas/textout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555484/updatelayeredwindow-with-normal-canvas-textout) but using `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` (as the accepted answer suggest) with LWA_COLORKEY or LWA_ALPHA is not working.

It's possible draw a control (TButton , TEdit) in a layered form which uses the `UpdateLayeredWindow` function?

Comment: Just a sidenote. I don't how to achieve this, but if you are going to make a solid color semi-transparent form without any special shaping, you can simply set the [`AlphaBlend`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.AlphaBlend) to True and [`AlphaBlendValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.AlphaBlendValue) to the desired alpha value ;-) But it's a good question in my view; +1.

Comment: I think your answer is at 4th and 5th paragraph of [Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#layered). Basically, if you want to continue to use your already existing painting code (VCL), use 'SetLayeredWindowAttributes'. If you'll draw everyting yourself, use 'UpdateLayeredWindow'.

Comment: @Sertac, just like the `AlphaBlend` and `AlphaBlendValue` properties do ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The documentation I refferred in the comment to the question is a bit obscure. The quote below from [Using Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507#layerwin_topic2a) (msdn) is much more explicit in that, *if you're going to use `UpdateLayeredWindows` you won't be able to use VCL supplied built-in painting framework*. The implication is that, you'll only see what you've drawn on the bitmap.

> To use **UpdateLayeredWindow**, the visual bits for a
>   layered window have to be rendered into a compatible bitmap. Then, via
>   a compatible GDI Device Context, the bitmap is provided to the
>   **UpdateLayeredWindow** API, along with the desired
>   color-key and alpha-blend information. The bitmap can also contain
>   per-pixel alpha information.
>
> Note that when using **UpdateLayeredWindow** the application doesn't need to respond to WM_PAINT or other painting
>   messages, because it has already provided the visual representation
>   for the window and the system will take care of storing that image,
>   composing it, and rendering it on the screen.
>   **UpdateLayeredWindow** is quite powerful, but it often
>   requires modifying the way an existing Win32 application draws.

Following code is an attempt to demonstrate how you can make the VCL pre-render the bitmap for you by using the `PaintTo` method of the form, before you apply your visual effects ( (it's not that I'm suggesting the use of this method, just trying to show what it would take to..). Also please note that, if all you're going to do is to *"make a solid color semi-transparent form*", TLama's suggestion in the comments to the question is the way to go.

I've put the code in a `WM_PRINTCLIENT` to have a *live* form. This is a bit pointless though, because not all actions requiring a visual indication will trigger a 'WM_PRINTCLIENT'. For instance in the below project, clicking the button or the check-box will be reflected on the form appearance, but writing in the memo will not.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure WMPrintClient(var Msg: TWMPrintClient); message WM_PRINTCLIENT;
  private
    FBitmap: TBitmap;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  Alpha = $D0;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  FBitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  FBitmap.SetSize(Width, Height);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FBitmap.Free;
end;


procedure TForm1.WMPrintClient(var Msg: TWMPrintClient);
var
  exStyle: DWORD;
  ClientOrg: TPoint;
  X, Y: Integer;
  Pixel: PRGBQuad;
  BlendFunction: TBlendFunction;
  BitmapPos: TPoint;
  BitmapSize: TSize;
begin
  exStyle := GetWindowLongA(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
  if (exStyle and WS_EX_LAYERED = 0) then
    SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle or WS_EX_LAYERED);

  // for non-client araea only
  FBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnShadow;
  FBitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0, FBitmap.Width, FBitmap.Height));

  // paste the client image
  ClientOrg.X := ClientOrigin.X - Left;
  ClientOrg.Y := ClientOrigin.Y - Top;
  FBitmap.Canvas.Lock;
  PaintTo(FBitmap.Canvas.Handle, ClientOrg.X, ClientOrg.Y);
  FBitmap.Canvas.Unlock;

  // set alpha and have pre-multiplied color values
  for Y := 0 to (FBitmap.Height - 1) do begin
    Pixel := FBitmap.ScanLine[Y];
    for X := 0 to (FBitmap.Width - 1) do begin
      Pixel.rgbRed := MulDiv($FF, Alpha, $FF);    // red tint
      Pixel.rgbGreen := MulDiv(Pixel.rgbGreen, Alpha, $FF);
      Pixel.rgbBlue := MulDiv(Pixel.rgbBlue, Alpha, $FF);
      Pixel.rgbReserved := Alpha;
      Inc(Pixel);
    end;
  end;

  BlendFunction.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
  BlendFunction.BlendFlags := 0;
  BlendFunction.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
  BlendFunction.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;

  BitmapPos := Point(0, 0);
  BitmapSize.cx := Width;
  BitmapSize.cy := Height;
  UpdateLayeredWindow(Handle, 0, nil, @BitmapSize, FBitmap.Canvas.Handle,
      @BitmapPos, 0, @BlendFunction, ULW_ALPHA);
end;
```

The above form looks like this:
[image: translucent form]

Answer (score 0):

You can always create form on form. It's not happiest solution, but it works. I beleive the best way to solve this problem would be by utilizing GDI+ or D2D, but unfortunately, I couldn't figure it out, so I went with "form on form" approach:

**Layered form:**

```
unit uLayeredForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Types,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Imaging.PngImage;

type
  TfrmLayered = class(TForm)
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FParentForm: TForm;
    procedure SetAlphaBackground(const AResourceName: String);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; const ABitmapResourceName: String); reintroduce;
    procedure UpdatePosition;
  end;

var
  frmLayered: TfrmLayered;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


constructor TfrmLayered.Create(AOwner: TComponent; const ABitmapResourceName: String);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  FParentForm := AOwner as TForm;
  SetAlphaBackground(ABitmapResourceName);
end;

procedure TfrmLayered.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Active) and (FParentForm.Visible) and (Assigned(FParentForm)) then
    FParentForm.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TfrmLayered.UpdatePosition;
begin
  if Assigned(FParentForm) then
  begin
    Left := FParentForm.Left - (ClientWidth - FParentForm.ClientWidth) div 2 - 1;
    Top := FParentForm.Top - (ClientHeight - FParentForm.ClientHeight) div 2 - 1;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmLayered.SetAlphaBackground(const AResourceName: String);
var
  blend_func: TBlendFunction;
  imgpos    : TPoint;
  imgsize   : TSize;
  exStyle   : DWORD;
  png       : TPngImage;
  bmp       : TBitmap;
begin
  // enable window layering
  exStyle := GetWindowLongA(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
  if ((exStyle and WS_EX_LAYERED) = 0) then
    SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle or WS_EX_LAYERED);

  png := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    png.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, AResourceName);

    bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      bmp.Assign(png);

      // resize the form
      ClientWidth := bmp.Width;
      ClientHeight := bmp.Height;

      // position image on form
      imgpos := Point(0, 0);
      imgsize.cx := bmp.Width;
      imgsize.cy := bmp.Height;

      // setup alpha blending parameters
      blend_func.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
      blend_func.BlendFlags := 0;
      blend_func.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
      blend_func.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;

      UpdateLayeredWindow(Handle, 0, nil, @imgsize, bmp.Canvas.Handle, @imgpos, 0, @blend_func, ULW_ALPHA);
    finally
      bmp.Free;
    end;
  finally
    png.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

**Main form:**

```
unit uMainForm;

interface

uses
  uLayeredForm, 
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    imgClose: TImage;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormHide(Sender: TObject);
    procedure imgCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FLayeredForm: TfrmLayered;
  protected
    procedure WMMove(var AMessage: TMessage); message WM_MOVE;
  public
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  uCommon, Vcl.Themes, Vcl.Styles.FormStyleHooks;



procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$IFDEF DEBUG} ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := TRUE; {$ENDIF}

  FLayeredForm := TfrmLayered.Create(self, 'MainBackground');
  FLayeredForm.Visible := TRUE;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FLayeredForm.Free;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormHide(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FLayeredForm.Hide;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.WMMove(var AMessage: TMessage);
begin
  if Assigned(FLayeredForm) then
    FLayeredForm.UpdatePosition;

  inherited;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FormMove(self, Button, Shift, X, Y);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FLayeredForm) then
  begin
    FLayeredForm.Show;
    FLayeredForm.UpdatePosition;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.imgCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

initialization
  TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TfrmMain, TFormStyleHookBackground);
  TFormStyleHookBackground.BackGroundSettings.Color := clBlack;
  TFormStyleHookBackground.BackGroundSettings.Enabled := TRUE;

end.
```

As you can see, you will have to do a bit of manual work to make two forms behave as one, but this code should get you started.

Since I needed form with smooth rounded borders, following screenshot is what I got as an end result. I coloured top form in gray, specifically for this post, for easier distinction between it and layered black form:

[image: Sample WS_EX_LAYERED form]

You can clearly see the difference between aliased gray form borders (made by [SetWindowRgn()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and CreateRoundRectRgn() APIs), and antialiased black form borders.